# Prevent redirect after node save

Tags: nodes

I have overlay turned off in Drupal. When I am editing a node, I want to prevent the redirect to the node after I hit save and just stay in the back-end. (It is really a pain to have to hit "edit" and have the page re-refresh each time when one is making a little tweak. As this can be easily achieved by having to tabs open; one for the node view and one for the backend edit form)

Is there an easy way to solve this in the configuration UI?

Comment: you could use the rules module. Or you could set $form_state['redirect'] in your own submit function. Or you could probably add a destination url parameter to the action of the form in a form_alter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can alter the form and add your own submit handler in which the user will be redirected back to the edit form:

```
function <MODULE>_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if (strstr($form_id, '_node_form')) {
      $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'] = array('<MODULE>_form_submit');
    }
}
// Custom submit handler for '_node_form'.
function <MODULE>_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Call default action.
  node_form_submit($form, $form_state);
  // Redirect back to the edit page for this node.
  $form_state['redirect'] = url('node/' . $form_state['nid'] . '/edit', array(
      'absolute' => TRUE
    )
  );

  $_GET['destination'] = $form_state['redirect'];
}
```

You might have to tweak the above code to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [Content Type Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_type_extras) module that will give you an option to configure a "save and new" buttons as well as a "save and edit button". Allows also to set defaults for other things in the content type forms.